# helm-projectile-recentf, "Can't rotate non image file"

Tags: debugging, images, error

When I hit `M-r` to get an exact match, `helm-projectile-recentf`, I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (cl-assertion-failed ((and (file-exists-p file) (string-match (image-file-name-regexp) file)) "Can't rotate non image file"))
  cl--assertion-failed((and (file-exists-p file) (string-match (image-file-name-regexp) file)) "Can't rotate non image file" nil nil)
```

I have no idea what that's supposed to mean;) Any pointers?;)

Turned on debugging and I see this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument consp nil)
  helm-set-attr(image-action2 helm-ff-rotate-image-right)
  helm-ff-rotate-right-persistent()
  funcall-interactively(helm-ff-rotate-right-persistent)
  call-interactively(helm-ff-rotate-right-persistent nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-ff-rotate-right-persistent)
  read-from-minibuffer(#("[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " 0 36 (face helm-minibuffer-prompt)) nil (keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e27393280>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e27382280>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e273e1280>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e273f0280>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e273af280>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e273be280>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e2737d280>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e2736c280>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e2734b280>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e2735a280>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e27339280>)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap (describe keymap (describe-mode . helm-help)))) (help keymap (109 . helm-help)) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode 0x19802e27328280>)) (8 keymap (109 . helm-help) (104 . undefined) (8 . undefined) (99 . helm-customize-group) (4 . helm-enable-or-switch-to-debug)) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (3 keymap (57 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1ea6ec975>)) (56 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1eab9c975>)) (55 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1eaa8c975>)) (54 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1ea9bc975>)) (53 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1ea8ac975>)) (52 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1ead5c975>)) (51 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1eac4c975>)) (50 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1eaf7c975>)) (49 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd7f1eae6c975>)) (110 . helm-helm-run-cycle-resume-with-subkeys) (108 . helm-display-line-numbers-mode) (62 . helm-toggle-truncate-line) (21 . helm-refresh) (6 . helm-follow-mode) (9 . helm-insert-or-copy) (11 . helm-kill-selection-and-quit) (25 . helm-yank-selection) (37 . helm-exchange-minibuffer-and-header-line) (95 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (45 . helm-swap-windows)) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) (67108989 . helm-narrow-window) (19 . undefined) (24 keymap (57 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665808b8975>)) (56 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665809a8975>)) (55 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665804d8975>)) (54 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665805c8975>)) (53 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665806f8975>)) (52 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd665807e8975>)) (51 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd66586e18975>)) (50 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd66586f08975>)) (49 . #f(compiled-function () (interactive nil) #<bytecode -0x47bd66586c38975>)) (2 . helm-resume-list-buffers-after-quit) (98 . helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit) (6 . helm-quit-and-find-file)) (11 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (67108896 . helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward) (0 . helm-toggle-visible-mark) (C-M-up . helm-scroll-other-window-down) (C-M-down . helm-scroll-other-window) (M-prior . helm-scroll-other-window-down) (M-next . helm-scroll-other-window) (12 . helm-recenter-top-bottom-other-window) (left . helm-previous-source) (right . helm-next-source) (15 . helm-next-source) (10 . helm-execute-persistent-action) (9 . helm-select-action) (13 . helm-maybe-exit-minibuffer) (7 . helm-keyboard-quit) (22 . helm-scroll-down) (27 keymap (110 . next-history-element) (112 . previous-history-element) (115 . undefined) (5 . helm-display-all-sources) (1 . helm-show-all-candidates-in-source) (85 . helm-unmark-all) (97 . helm-mark-all) (109 . helm-toggle-all-marks) (41 . helm-next-visible-mark) (40 . helm-prev-visible-mark) (91) (32 . helm-toggle-visible-mark-backward) (33554454 . helm-scroll-other-window-down) (25 . helm-scroll-other-window-down) (22 . helm-scroll-other-window) (12 . helm-reposition-window-other-window) (111 . helm-previous-source) (62 . helm-end-of-buffer) (60 . helm-beginning-of-buffer) (118 . helm-scroll-up)) (next . helm-next-page) (prior . helm-previous-page) (C-up . helm-follow-action-backward) (C-down . helm-follow-action-forward) (16 . helm-previous-line) ...) nil nil #("using" 0 5 (face font-lock-keyword-face fontified t)) t)
  helm-read-from-minibuffer("[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " nil nil nil nil nil nil)
  helm-internal(helm-source-projectile-recentf-list nil "[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " nil nil "*helm projectile: poc.envdte*" nil nil nil)
  apply(helm-internal (helm-source-projectile-recentf-list nil "[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " nil nil "*helm projectile: poc.envdte*" nil nil nil))
  helm(helm-source-projectile-recentf-list nil "[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " nil nil "*helm projectile: poc.envdte*" nil nil nil)
  apply(helm (helm-source-projectile-recentf-list nil "[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: " nil nil "*helm projectile: poc.envdte*" nil nil nil))
  helm(:sources helm-source-projectile-recentf-list :buffer "*helm projectile: poc.envdte*" :truncate-lines nil :prompt "[poc.envdte] Recently visited file: ")
  helm-projectile-recentf(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-projectile-recentf nil)
  call-interactively(helm-projectile-recentf nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-projectile-recentf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you've tried to rotate a file that is not recognized as being an image file.

Turn on debugging: `M-x set-variable RET debug-on-error RET t RET`, and check the resulting debugger backtrace, to see what went wrong.

You can step through the execution of whatever function raised the error, using `debug-on-entry`. For example, if you want to step through `helm-projectile-recentf`, then use `M-x debug-on-entry RET helm-projectile-recentf RET`. Then, when that function is called you'll enter the Elisp debugger, and you can step through it with `d` to see what it didn't like.